# Can't connect to mysql service in minikube from spring boot pod

Tags: mysql

I am running mysql and a spring boot application in a minikube cluster. But the spring boot app can't connect to the mysql instance. Here are my kubernetes configurations.

**Spring App deployment**

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: expense-manager-deployment
  labels:
    group: expense-manager
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: expense-manager-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: expense-manager-app
    spec:
      # We can specify multiple container to run inside the spec
      containers:
        - name: expenser-manager-service
          image: gyanaranjan1993/expense-manager-app:2.0.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
              value: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/expense_manager
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
              value: expense_manager_user
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
              value: expense_manager_password
```

**mysql deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:latest
          name: mysql
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: password
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: expense_manager
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              value: expense_manager_user
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              value: expense_manager_password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

**mysql service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
```

This is the error I get.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'expense_manager_user'@'10.244.0.70' (using password: YES)
```

I tried looking up the user and host name in mysql console and looks like the user `expense_manager_user` is mapped to `localhost`. Is that the most probable problem ?

Comment: Yep, you need to change your mysql user to allow connection from remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` variable is pointing to `mysql://mysql:3306/expense_manager` and your service name is `mysql-service` so it should be like `mysql://mysql-service:3306/expense_manager`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I updated it, but it still does not work and throws same error.